# How to tell the Play Store to list apps in different languages?

Tags: google-play-store, languages, localization

Apparently the search in the Play Store only returns results of apps that belong in some way to the locale my phone is set to.

For example, there is an app from a German bus company with their schedule. If I type the exact name of the app into the search field it doesn't show this this app in the results because my phone is set to English.

The only way to find it is in the browser Google Play website when I am not logged into my Google account.

Is there a way to circumvent this and let Google Play present *all* the apps with this name?